# How to pass the data while using two foreach loop in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

```
    public function index2(){

        $s_books = raws::orderBy('sequence', 'ASC')->where('type',"book")->get();

            foreach ($s_books as $data) {
                $menu="{$data->menu}";
                  $main_books = books::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where("menu",$menu)->get();
            }
    return view('index')->with(['main_books'=>$main_books]);}
```

And this is Blade

```
    @foreach($main_books as $data)
        {{$data->id}}
    @endforeach
```

But this is showing only the last data.
How can I show all tha data in $main_book in laravel blade???

Answer (score 0):

The code you have, you will get only the last item, you need to put all in an array. Try this code in you `controller`.

```php
$main_books = [];

foreach ($s_books as $data) {
$menu="{$data->menu}";
array_push($main_books, books::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where("menu",$menu)->get());
}
```